# "set -e" does not cause a code block to exit if in a conditional

Tags: bash

I'm trying to figure out why the bail-on-error behavior `-e` does not kick in if the failing block is in a conditional chain:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
{       echo "First"
        ls blat
        echo "(this should not print)"
}
```

Prints out:

```
First
ls: cannot access 'blat': No such file or directory
```

which is correct.

Whereas the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
{       echo "First"
        ls blat
        echo "(this should not print)"
} || echo "Encountered an error"
```

Prints out:

```
First
ls: cannot access 'blat': No such file or directory
(this should not print)
```

I expect `Encountered an error` to be printed instead of `this should not print`

Can anybody explain to me the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: That's behaving as documented, and it *has to be*. Otherwise, your conditionals would be useless; the false branches of them would never run.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) -- skipping the allegory for the exercises below if in a hurry.

Comment: You could run the commands in a subshell `( set -e; echo "First" ... )` and test exit status after: `[[ $? -eq 0 ]] || echo "Error"`.

Comment: @PesaThe, I'm not sure I'd describe that as a complete and general solution -- move that code into a function, put the function's invocation in a conditional, and then you're sunk again. So if you write code depending on `set -e`, then *all calling stack frame layers* need to be written with awareness of that code in mind.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, 100% :) I wouldn't use `set -e` in my code at all. That's why I didn't write it as an answer. It was more like: what could you change in your code to make it "work" in this case.

Comment: I didn't know that there was a BashFAQ site, probably the most useful thing I get out of this question...! Also I had forgotten that `set -e` wouldn't exit block, but would exit shell. That's me mixing my concepts up. Thanks setting me straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation (emphasis mine):

> The shell does not exit
>                         if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following  a  while  or  until
>                         keyword,  part of the test following the if or elif reserved words, **part of any command executed
>                         in a && or || list** except the command following the final && or ||, any command  in  a  pipeline
>                         but  the last, or if the command's return value is being inverted with !.

Because `ls` is part of the `{...}` compound executed as a non-final part of the `||` list, the script does not exit when `ls` has a non-zero exit status.

Comment: Of course, I also forgot that `set -e` (if triggered) would cause an exit of the subshell, not simply of the block. Thanks.

Comment: @taifwa There isn't a subshell involved here. `( )` would force a subshell, but `{ }` doesn't.